# Start vs. First

Tags: word-difference

I understand that **start** is a verb and **first** is an adverb. I totally understand their meanings as individual words. I just don't understand their meanings in the context and how to use them. I'll try to form a sentence and please tell me the difference in meaning between them.

- When I **started** learning English, I found it hard.
- When I **first** learned English, I found it hard.
- If you've **started** to save money a long time ago, you would be rich now.

I think I can't add **first** to the previous sentence, right? Can I combine start and first in one sentence? If yes, Does that add something to the meaning?

Comment: But you haven't combined them in any way. There are many possible ways I can think of that you *could* use both words in the same sentence—but it's not clear to me what you had in mind. Please edit your question to give an example of such a combination so we can comment on its suitability.

Comment: Do you mean the following? `If you'd first saved money, you would be rich now`.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik yes I do

Comment: @Jason Bassford Here's what I can think of: When I first started learning English, I found it hard.

Comment: That sentence is fine. Although it's not as common to say *first started* as just *started*, it's still said sometimes.